# MACD plot in python similar to tradingview figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, moving-average, quantitative-finance, mplfinance

Here is an example of MACD plot using python.

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/algo-trading/python-mplfinance-plot-yfinance-candle-chart-moving-average-macd-and-volume/

I'd like the result (including colors and crossover points, etc.) to be the same as that of tradingview.com

https://www.tradingview.com/script/NDH8bJow-MACD-Colors-Signals/

Could anybody show the python so that it is the same as that of tradingview.com?

Answer (score 1):

> Could anybody show the python so that it is the same as that of tradingview.com?

I don't think anyone is going to want to write your code for you.
However what I would recommend is that you work through the mplfinance tutorials on [Customizing the Appearance of Your Plots](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/customization_and_styles.md) ***and especially teach yourself about*** [**mplfinance styles**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/styles.ipynb) which shows how to modify the overall color scheme of your plot.  See also [mplfinance style sheets reference](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Mplfinance-Style-Sheets-Reference).

For example, to achieve a color scheme similar to trading view you could use the "market colors" from style 'yahoo' and the combine that with mplfinance style 'nightclouds'.  Something like this:

```py
mc = mpf.make_marketcolors(base_mpf_style='yahoo')
s  = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpf_style='nightclouds',marketcolors=mc)
```

Then when you call `mpf.plot()` specify kwarg `style=s`

hth